# Why tab name is plural for an object in salesforce Admin

Tags: salesforce, admin

I was wondering why tab name by default is plural in salesforce admin when we create an object.

Example:- If we create an object with List then Tab name automatically gets created with "Lists"

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce, if we create a Tab for an object we are actually creating a link for all the associated records in that object. Hence, by default Salesforce gives a plural name for an object we are tying to create

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce, the tab name is typically plural because it represents a collection of records for a specific object. For example, if you have an object named "Account," the corresponding tab name would be "Accounts" because it displays a list of all the accounts in your organization.

Using a plural name for the tab also follows the convention of representing collections of objects with plural names in database design and programming.

In addition, using a plural name for the tab can help users understand that they are working with a collection of records, rather than a single record. This can be particularly helpful for new users who are learning to navigate the Salesforce interface.